# How can achieve this CoordinatorLayout where Button below WebView

Tags: android, xml, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a CoordinatorLayout with a WebView and a Button. i want to add the button below to the WebView? So that WebView take full space and Button take remaining space for itself.

Here is the Example:
[image: a busy cat]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But the problem is that it's always overlap the WebView. How can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why you use CoordinatorLayout

use ConstraintLayout for example if you don't have a specific need like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout          
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```